# Which is correct, "lines of sight" or "line of sights" when referring to one observer to many object?

Tags: grammar, plural-forms

Which is correct?

> 1. lines of sight
> 2. line of sights

When referring to one observer to many object?

I understand it would be "line of sight" when referring to a single path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, the traditional rule is that to make a phrase including a noun plural, you pluralize the noun, and not any adjective or adjective phrases.

The classic examples always given in English classes are the odd cases where the adjective follows the noun. Like the plural of "court martial" is "courts martial", not "court martials", because "martial" here is an adjective meaning "having to do with the military", and there is more than one court, not more than one "martial". Or, the plural of "mother-in-law" is "mothers-in-law", NOT "mother-in-laws", because there is more than one mother, not more than one law.

So in this case, it's "lines of sight", NOT "line of sights", because there is more than one line, not more than one sight.

Many English speakers, even fluent ones, pluralize the last word in the phrase rather than the noun. I'd call this simply wrong, though I suppose those who believe that majority always wins in grammar might say that the fact that so many do it makes it right.

Answer (score 3):

*Sight* in this context means "power of vision", not something worth seeing, and so is uncountable and cannot be pluralized.

In any case, if you have a noun phrase of the form [noun] [prepositional phrase], the noun phrase is pluralized by pluralizing the initial noun.

- "rights of way"
- "rules of procedure"
- "enchantments under the sea"